# Binomial RVs: probability of $k$th success occurring by time $n$ (Çinlar, Exercise 5.26)

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

My question is Exercise 5.26 on p.90 of Çinlar's *Probability and Stochastics*. Here is the (slightly paraphrased) exercise:

> 5.26 (*Times of successes*) Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with the same success probability $p$. For each integer $n \geq 1$, define $S_n := X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. (Thus, $S_n$ is the number of successes occuring during the time interval $[1,n]$.)  Define, for each integer $k \geq 1$, the time of the $k^{\text{th}}$ success by
>
> $$ T_k(\omega) = \inf \{ n \geq 1: S_n(\omega) \geq k\}, \quad \omega \in \Omega. $$
> Note that this yields $T_k(\omega) = +\infty$ if $S_n(\omega) < k$ for all $n$. Show that $T_k$ is a random variable for each $k \geq 1$. Show that, for integers $n \geq k$,
>
> \begin{align*}   
> \mathbb{P}\{T_k = n \} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)! (n-k)!} p^k q^{n-k}, \quad \mathbb{P}\{T_k \leq n \} = \sum_{j=k}^{n} \frac{n!}{j! (n-j)!} p^j q^{n-j}. \quad (*)
> \end{align*}
>
> Show in particular that $T_k <  \infty$ almost surely and, therefore, that $\lim S_n = +\infty$ almost surely.

My only issue is with showing that $\mathbb{P}\{T_k \leq n \} = \sum_{j=k}^{n} \frac{n!}{j! (n-j)!} p^j q^{n-j}$. My thinking is that since the events $\{T_k = k \}, \{T_k = k+1\} \ldots,\{T_k = n\}$ form a partition of $\{T_k \leq n\}$, we have
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{P}\{T_k  \leq n\} &= \sum_{j=k}^{n} \mathbb{P}\{T_k  = j \}  = \sum_{j=k}^{n}  \frac{(j-1)!}{(k-1)! (j-k)!} p^k q^{j-k},
\end{align*}
where the second inequality is by the first formula in $(*)$. Is this correct? And if so, how do I show that
$$ \sum_{j=k}^{n}  \frac{(j-1)!}{(k-1)! (j-k)!} p^k q^{j-k} = \sum_{j=k}^{n} \frac{n!}{j! (n-j)!} p^j q^{n-j} \; ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is also valid and equivalent.

First, the textbook's expression is obtained by observing that the event $T_k \le n$ means that it takes at most $n$ Bernoulli trials to observe the $k^{\rm th}$ success; equivalently, this means $$S_n \ge k,$$ i.e. the sum of the first $n$ Bernoulli trials is at least $k$.  And since $S_n$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, it follows that $$\Pr[T_k \le n] = \Pr[S_n \ge k] = \sum_{j=k}^n \binom{n}{j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j},$$ as claimed.  This relationship between the binomial and negative binomial distributions is an important one that you will encounter in the future.

At this time I don't have an algebraic proof of the equivalence of the two sums, but perhaps someone else will write one or will point to a reference, as I believe it should be straightforward.